# Mach Threads Not Working on x86_64

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, mach

I'm trying to write a simple "Hello, world!" program using Mach threads on x86_64. Unfortunately, the program crashes with a segmentation fault on my machine, and I can't seem to fix the problem. I couldn't find much documentation about Mach threads online, but I referred to the following [C file](http://web.mit.edu/mmadinot/Desktop/mmadinot/MacData/afs/athena.mit.edu/software/julia_v0.2.0/julia/src/init.c) which also makes use of Mach threads.

As far as I can tell, I'm doing everything correctly. I suspect that the segmentation fault is because I did not set up the thread's stack correctly, but I took the same approach as the reference file, which has the following code.

```
// This is for alignment. In particular note that the sizeof(void*) is necessary
// since it would usually specify the return address (i.e. we are aligning the call
// frame to a 16 byte boundary as required by the abi, but the stack pointer
// to point to the byte beyond that. Not doing this leads to funny behavior on
// the first access to an external function will fail due to stack misalignment
state.__rsp &= -16;
state.__rsp -= sizeof(void*);
```

Do you have any idea as to what I could be doing wrong?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <system_error>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <mach/mach_init.h>
#include <mach/mach_types.h>
#include <mach/task.h>
#include <mach/thread_act.h>
#include <mach/thread_policy.h>
#include <mach/i386/thread_status.h>

void check(kern_return_t err)
{
        if (err == KERN_SUCCESS) {
                return;
        }

        auto code = std::error_code{err, std::system_category()};
        switch (err) {
        case KERN_FAILURE:
                throw std::system_error{code, "failure"};
        case KERN_INVALID_ARGUMENT:
                throw std::system_error{code, "invalid argument"};
        default:
                throw std::system_error{code, "unknown error"};
        }
}

void test()
{
        std::cout << "Hello from thread." << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
        auto page_size = ::getpagesize();
        auto stack = new uint8_t[page_size];
        auto thread = ::thread_t{};
        auto task = ::mach_task_self();
        check(::thread_create(task, &thread));

        auto state = ::x86_thread_state64_t{};
        auto count = ::mach_msg_type_number_t{x86_THREAD_STATE64_COUNT};
        check(::thread_get_state(thread, x86_THREAD_STATE64,
                (::thread_state_t)&state, &count));

        auto stack_ptr = (uintptr_t)(stack + page_size);
        stack_ptr &= -16;
        stack_ptr -= sizeof(void*);

        state.__rip = (uintptr_t)test;
        state.__rsp = (uintptr_t)stack_ptr;
        state.__rbp = (uintptr_t)stack_ptr;
        check(::thread_set_state(thread, x86_THREAD_STATE64,
                (::thread_state_t)&state, x86_THREAD_STATE64_COUNT));

        check(::thread_resume(thread));
        ::sleep(1);
        std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;
}
```

The reference file uses C++11; if compiling with GCC or Clang, you will need to supply the `std=c++11` flag.

Comment: how does it crash? is it one of your exceptions?

Comment: @GradyPlayer No, it's a segmentation fault. It occurs after the call to sleep, presumably because the created thread triggers an access violation.